# NullPointerException when trying to read data from Excel file using Selenium

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I am creating a Selenium project using Maven, wherein I am trying to read 'username' and 'password' from  an Excel file (xlsx).

Here is the code -

```
public class NewTest {

WebDriver driver;


@BeforeTest
public void setup() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",Util.FIREFOX_PATH);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to(Util.BASE_URL);
}
    

public void readExcel(String filePath, String fileName, String sheetName) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    File file = new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
    Workbook workBook = null;
    String fileExtensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));
    if (fileExtensionName.equals(".xlsx")) {
        workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs); 
    }
    if (fileExtensionName.equals(".xls")) {
        workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    }
    Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheet(sheetName);
    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
            
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j+1).getStringCellValue());
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
            String expectedTitle = "Home Page";
            SoftAssert sassert = new SoftAssert();
            sassert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
            sassert.assertAll();
            break;
        }
    }
    
}

@Test
public static void callingFunction() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    NewTest newTest = new NewTest();
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Sitesh\\Desktop";
    newTest.readExcel(filePath, "Book2.xlsx", "Sheet1");
}
}
```

I am getting the following error -

```
FAILED: callingFunction
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Guru99_Bank.Guru99_Bank.NewTest.readExcel(NewTest.java:59)
at Guru99_Bank.Guru99_Bank.NewTest.callingFunction(NewTest.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:599)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:822)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Screenshot of Excel file-
[image]

The error I am getting is in this line:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());

Comment: Null point exception occouring when driver instances are different class by class.confirm you are using same driver instance 
please create and use global variable for driver instance

Which design pattern you are using Page object model or Page factory?

Comment: I am not using any framework, neither POM, nor Page Factory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue - Null pointer exception**

You are trying to access unavailable cell

```
sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j+1)
```

This is trying to move toward the next cell from the current one, but that cell doesn't exist

**How does Excel reader work?**

Firstly gets the first row and it parses all the cells, one by one sequentially. If no cell is available it goes to the next row.

If you try to access "two cells" in the same loop (sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j+1)) it will work only if you have data in those cells, if not you'll get an NP exception cause nothing is there.

This picture might clarify it to you
[image]

**Solution:**

```
//rows
for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        //cells
        for (int j = 0; j < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); j++) {
            // gettingrow cell
            Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
            String expectedTitle = "Home Page";
            SoftAssert sassert = new SoftAssert();
            sassert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
            sassert.assertAll();
        }
    }
```

also - use getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - it return only the rows/cells with data.

**Later update for NP exception**

you need to add the webdriver as a parameter for your excel method. The webdriver gets an instance but when the readExcel method uses is null, so you need to pass the initialized object.

Change the method to

```
public void readExcel(String filePath, String fileName, String sheetName, WebDriver driver)
```

and this call to

```
newTest.readExcel(filePath, "Book2.xlsx", "Sheet1", driver);
```

and it will work.

Comment: Thanks. But I am still getting the exception. After isolating the problem as suggested by @Senthil Kumar Vaithiyanathan 's, I found that the exception is due to line Element e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']"));

Comment: can you paste the URL to see the issue?

Comment: I hope you meant web url by the term 'URL'. Here the link:    https://github.com/Sachindra7/Selenium-Guru99-Bank/blob/master/Guru99-Bank/src/test/java/Guru99_Bank/Guru99_Bank/NewTest.java     -- Btw, error is coming on line 60.   It's surprising to me that this line is throwing 'NullPointerException' , because generally it used to throw 'element not found' exception, if Selenium had any difficulty locating the element.

Comment: found the issue, check my answer - I updated it for your needs

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a savior! Do we need to pass the driver object as parameter every-time while dealing with the Excel? Or this is just one peculiar scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting NullPointerException, you are using chaining of methods it is better split into smaller & understand which object is actually null to find reason. Without that information, people in the forum may not able to help out

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());`

Something like

`Element e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")); Row row = sheet.getRow(i); Cell c = row.getCell(j); String val = c.getStringCellValue();`

Here element, row or cell might be null.

Comment: Yes, after following your suggestion, I found out that NullPointerException is occuring on line Element e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")); My xpath is correct, Can you figure out what is the problem here?